# Labelling Individual Functions in a Table of Plots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, legending

How do I label individual functions in a plot that contains 25 functions in a list? Where do I put the range for the iteration variable "i" in the String Form of the Callout of the Parametric Plot and Plot? I've tried subsituting \phi on "i" instead but that doesn't work since \phi is the range of the plot and not the iteration from 1 to 25 of the plots.

```
    R[r_] := 2/(5*3)*1/(2*3)!*((2*r)/(5*3))^(2*3)*E^((-2*r)/(5*3))
SampleInitialConditions = N[Table[R[r], {r, 0, 100, 4}]];
SampleInitialConditionsMatrix = 
  List@N[Table[{r, R[r]}, {r, 0, 100, 4}]];

LabelString = Table[StringForm["# ``", LS], {LS, 1, 25}];
ColorList = {Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red, Brown}, i]}, {i, 
      1/25, 1, 1/25}]} // Flatten;
   
ColorList = {Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red, Brown}, i]}, {i, 
      1/25, 1, 1/25}]} // Flatten;
      
LegendWith = 
  SwatchLegend[ColorList, LabelString, 
   LegendLabel -> "With Photophoresis", LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
   LegendLayout -> "Row"];
LegendWithout = 
  SwatchLegend[ColorList, LabelString, 
   LegendLabel -> "Without Photophoresis", LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
   LegendLayout -> "Row"];
   
ALPHAkWITH = Table[0.002*P*B, {P, 1, 6}, {B, 1, 6}];
ALPHAkWITHOUT = Table[0.001*P*B, {P, 1, 6}, {B, 1, 6}];
      
NumericalDiffequaWith = 
  Table[NDSolve[{q[\[Phi]] + 
       q''[\[Phi]] == -(ALPHAkWITH[[1, 1]]/(1 + q[\[Phi]]))^2, 
     q[0] == R[r], q'[0] == R[r]}, q, {\[Phi], 0, 100}], {r, 0, 100, 
    4}];
    
NumericalDiffequaWithout = 
  Table[NDSolve[{q[\[Phi]] + 
       q''[\[Phi]] == -(ALPHAkWITHOUT[[1, 1]]/(1 + q[\[Phi]]))^2, 
     q[0] == R[r], q'[0] == R[r]}, q, {\[Phi], 0, 100}], {r, 0, 100, 
    4}];
    
NumericalCartesianPlot = Show[ 
   
   Plot[Callout[Evaluate[q[\[Phi]] /. NumericalDiffequaWith], StringForm["Test # ``", i],Above], {\[Phi], 0, 
     100}, PlotStyle -> ColorList, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LegendWith, {Top, Left}], ImageSize -> 900],
   Plot[Callout[Evaluate[q[\[Phi]] /. NumericalDiffequaWithout], StringForm["Test # ``", i],Above], {\[Phi], 0, 
     100}, PlotStyle -> ColorList, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LegendWithout, {Bottom, Right}], 
    ImageSize -> 900],
   PlotLabel -> 
    "Positions of With and Without Photophoresis of a particle with 1\[Mu]m",
   Frame -> True
   ]
   
NumericalParametricPlot1 = Show[ 
   
   ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[Callout[{q[\[Phi]], q'[\[Phi]]} /. 
      NumericalDiffequaWith], StringForm["Test # ``", i],Above], {\[Phi], 0, 100}, 
    PlotStyle -> ColorList, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LegendWith, {Top, Left}], ImageSize -> 600],
   ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[Callout[{q[\[Phi]], q'[\[Phi]]} /. 
      NumericalDiffequaWithout], StringForm["Test # ``", i],Above], {\[Phi], 0, 100}, 
    PlotStyle -> ColorList, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LegendWithout, {Bottom, Right}], 
    ImageSize -> 600],
   PlotLabel -> 
    "Orbits of With and Without Photophoresis of a particle with 1\[Mu]m",
   Frame -> True
   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there. But you misplaced the "Evaluate" command:

```
NumericalParametricPlot1 = 
 Show[ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    Callout[{q[\[Phi]], q'[\[Phi]]} /. NumericalDiffequaWith, 
     StringForm["Test # ``", i], Above]], {\[Phi], 0, 100}, 
   PlotStyle -> ColorList, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LegendWith, {Top, Left}], ImageSize -> 600], 
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    Callout[{q[\[Phi]], q'[\[Phi]]} /. NumericalDiffequaWithout, 
     StringForm["Test # ``", i], Above]], {\[Phi], 0, 100}, 
   PlotStyle -> ColorList, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LegendWithout, {Bottom, Right}], 
   ImageSize -> 600], 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Orbits of With and Without Photophoresis of a particle with \
1\[Mu]m", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've switched those functions now and those errors are now absent. But the labels are still missing.

Comment: You need a separate Callout command for every label.